# Change the border color of a progress bar in quickchart js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, progress, quickchart

i'm using [quickchart.js](https://quickchart.io/documentation/) to create a progress bar and i have a problem. When I create a progress bar by assigning it a background color it works but there is a permanent blue border that I can't remove.
[Here the first example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQvD9.png)

I tried to change the color of the border but it does not change this border.
[Here the second example with border color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbC2j.png)

```
{
  type: 'progressBar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: '#32cd32',
      data: [50],
      datalabels: {
          font: {
              style: 'Arial',
              size: 18,
          }
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Is there a possibility to remove this border or change its color ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a second `dataset` that specifies the total (100%) of the progress bar.

In order to remove the border, this could look as follows:

```
{
  type: 'progressBar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: '#32cd32',
      data: [50]
    },
    {      
      borderColor: 'white',
      data: [100]
    }]
  }
}
```

Simply change `borderColor` in case you want a specific border to be drawn.